# How to find matrix $S$

Tags: matrix-equations

how to find matrix  $\mathbb{S}$
$\mathbb{S}\Lambda\mathbb{S}^T=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \quad & \ast \\
\quad & \ddots \quad \\
\ast &\quad&1
\end{bmatrix}$ where

$
\Lambda=\begin{bmatrix}
\mu_1 & 0 & 0&0 \\
0 &\mu_2&0&0 \\
0 &0&\ddots&0\\
0&0&0&\mu_n
\end{bmatrix}$
and $\mu_1,\mu_2,...,\mu_n>0.$

Comment: Take the help of determinants

Comment: What do you mean by *?

Comment: symmetric matrix